# Android EditText issue

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, egl

I have an editText field in my app and the keyboard pops up when I focus the text field on lower APIs than 10. For some reson, the keyboard doesnt show when the editText is focused in APIs higher than 10. Also in API higher than 10, in the logcat it says eglSurfaceAttribute not implemented whenever I focus the EditText field. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What behaviour do you want to see? The keyboard showing or the keyboard not showing?

Comment: I want the keyboard to show when the EditText is focused. When ever i focus it, I get the message eglSurfaceAttribute not implemented.

Comment: Are you using the Android emulator or a real device?

Comment: I'm using an android emulator (Nexus One). I also tested it on a samsung galaxy s4, it is still having the same issue.

Comment: How are you requesting for focus on the `EditText`?

Comment: I have the Foucusable and Foucsable in touch mode properties checked. For the input type, I have it set to number. Thanks

Comment: "in the logcat it says eglSurfaceAttribute not implemented whenever I focus the EditText field." **Ignore** the message, you'll be able to use the keypad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to bring up the soft keyboard when `EditText` is focused is to add `<requestFocus/>` to the `EditText` in the XML layout.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Yes, it worked. I also disabled the use of computer keyboard input in the AVD setting, it seemed to work too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just put this line on your onCreate()

```
editText.requestFocus();
```